# PHP 5.3 mbstring install

Tags: php, centos

I'm trying to install the mbstring module on PHP 5.3, CentOS 5.

```
$ yum install mbstring
--> Missing Dependency: php-common = 5.2.10-1.el5.centos for package: php-mbstring
```

I do an rpm -qa and found that I have php-common-5.3.8-1.w5 installed. How can I install mbstring with this newer php-common? I should note that php is working just fine, just trying to get this module installed.

Thanks.

### grep base /etc/yum.repos.d/*

```
$ grep base /etc/yum.repos.d/*
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:[base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Debuginfo.repo:baseurl=http://debuginfo.centos.org/5/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Media.repo:baseurl=file:///media/CentOS/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Testing.repo:baseurl=http://dev.centos.org/centos/$releasever/testing/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:[C5.5-base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.5/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.5/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.5/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.5/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:[C5.4-base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.4/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.4/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.4/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.4/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:[C5.3-base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.3/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.3/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.3/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.3/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:[C5.2-base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.2/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.2/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.2/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.2/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:[C5.1-base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.1/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.1/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.1/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.1/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:[C5.0-base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.0/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.0/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.0/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Vault.repo:baseurl=http://vault.centos.org/5.0/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:[base]
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=updates
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/updates/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=addons
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/addons/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=extras
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/extras/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/centosplus/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=contrib
/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS.repo:#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/contrib/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - Testing - $basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/5/$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=testing-epel5&arch=$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - Testing - $basearch - Debug
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/5/$basearch/debug
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=testing-debug-epel5&arch=$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - Testing - $basearch - Source
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/testing/5/SRPMS
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel-testing.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=testing-source-epel5&arch=$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-5&arch=$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Debug
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/$basearch/debug
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-debug-5&arch=$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:name=Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 5 - $basearch - Source
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:#baseurl=http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/SRPMS
/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo:mirrorlist=http://mirrors.fedoraproject.org/mirrorlist?repo=epel-source-5&arch=$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo:name=Les RPM de remi pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo:#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/remi/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo:name=Les RPM de remi en test pour Enterprise Linux $releasever - $basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo:#baseurl=http://rpms.famillecollet.com/enterprise/$releasever/test/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/scalr.repo:baseurl=http://rpm.scalr.net/rpm/rhel/$releasever/$basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:name=Webtatic Repository $releasever - $basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:#baseurl=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/$basearch/
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:mirrorlist=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/$basearch/mirrorlist
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:name=Webtatic Repository $releasever - $basearch - Debug
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:#baseurl=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/$basearch/debug/
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:mirrorlist=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/$basearch/debug/mirrorlist
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:name=Webtatic Repository $releasever - $basearch
/etc/yum.repos.d/webtatic.repo:#baseurl=http://repo.webtatic.com/yum/centos/5/SRPMS/
```

Comment: Where did you get and how did you install the PHP 5.3.8 package as that is non-standard on CentOS.

Comment: I believe I used http://rpms.famillecollet.com/ repo

Comment: Does that repo also contain the mbstring RPM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the non-standard repo you obtained PHP from also has the RPM for php-mb: `yum --disablerepo=epel install php-mbstring`

Comment: It looks like the RPM is in that repo so unless you have some other repos I am unaware of, that above command should bring it down.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the command ran, but I'm getting the same error as before

Comment: Now, that I think of it, I used webtatic for the repo. http://www.webtatic.com/packages/php53/

Comment: Can you show us the output of `grep base /etc/yum.repos.d/*` please?

Comment: Hi, the output is in my post now, thanks for the help so far.

Comment: You may want to backout and start fresh with something from the EPEL or IUS. Those two organizations have well maintained repos and fewer dependency issues.

Comment: I got it to work, something was messed up with my webtatic repo. mbstring is now installed. Thanks for the help. @jeffatrackaid, EPEL is what I'm going to start using, it is very recommended by CentOS. Thanks everyone.

Comment: Great! I have also learned the hard way to keep my repos to a minimum with the yum package manager, especially since epel takes so long to catch up to "bleeding edge" versions.

Answer (score 1):

The error you are receiving is saying that the php-mbstring package depends on the "php-common" package, of the specific version "5.2.10-1.el5.centos".

This probably means that you are trying to install the php-mbstring RPM from the standard CentOS base repo, but you seem to have php-common from elsewhere.

Show us the output of "yum info php-mbstring" and "yum info php-common".